# Change characters in a string array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, character

I try to change 'a' characters into 'e', in a string array. But I receive an error `*pos = 'e';`  line. It says "Main.exe has stopped working". I could not understand the problem. Do you have any idea?

```
int main(void) {
    char *sehirler[] = { "Istanbul", "Ankara", "Izmir", "\0" };
    int i;
    for (i = 0; *sehirler[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        char *pos = sehirler[i];
        while (*pos != '\0') {
            if (*pos == 'a') {
                printf("%c", *pos);
                *pos = 'e';          //ERRROR
            }
            pos++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yours is not a string array, it's an array of pointers to string literals, and you can't change string literals.

To make it an array try this

```
int main(int argc, char *argb[])
{
    char sehirler[4][9] = {"Istanbul", "Ankara", "Izmir", ""};
    /*            ^  ^
     *            |  |__ Number of characters in `Istanbul' + '\0'
     *            |_ Number of strings in the array
     */
    int   i;
    for (i = 0 ; *sehirler[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
    {
        char *pos = sehirler[i];
        while (*pos != '\0')
        {
            if (*pos == 'a')
            {
                printf("%c", *pos);
                *pos = 'e';          //ERRROR
            }
            pos++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

you might need to allocate space with `malloc()` and then use `strcpy()` to make a copy of the literals, then the copy will be modifiable.